# How to encrypt the address bar url using asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How to encrypt this url in asp.net (VB.NET), so that user cannot view this address bar text in their browser address bar ?

http://localhost:2486/volvobusesindia/passenger_info.aspx?from=Delhi&to=Manali&journey=21-Nov-2010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.  And before someone suggests using POST, that doesn't really hide anything.  It's trivial to use Wireshark, Firebug, etc. either way.

Any communication between the user's machine and your server, in either direction, encrypted or unencrypted, can be monitored by the user.

EDIT: An alternative is to generate a unique GUID or session identifier, then keep track of the meaning on the server.  This is not encryption, but it may serve the desired purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can do some really good obfuscating, but you probably want to roll-your-own, as if you are using this for security, you don't want everybody knowing how to decode your encoding.

We do it by using a single querystring parameter that contains ALL of the information we need from the request in our own format.  Of course, this does mean giving up all of the handy .Request[] methods, but you've got to make the trade off somewhere.

The full path to a file with the fully encrypted URL also can get obscenely long with everything thrown in there.  For example, this is a link that will display an image of a ring with the word "Landrum" on it (in both directions).  The image is created the moment you request it, from the information contained in the encrypted query string.

http://www.flipscript.com/data/default/images/catalog/medium/AMBIRingTitanBlue_G1F88E4X57,409-945,591O0M0S2V6.jpgx?xq=45C35129$6zvtnw6m1280kwz8ucqjt6jjb2vtea43bio5ixmnge-5r4i-o1o32j43y58nv

I hope that helps a bit!  There is no "out of the box" solution, but this one works pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hiding it, you could call this site internally from within some other site and do whatever you wish with the returned results (e.g. display them on your site). That would guarantee you that the user won't ever have the chance to see the actual site being called.