# How to encrypt query string in vb.net?

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, query-string

How to encrypt query string in vb.net ?

http://localhost:2486/volvobusesindia/passenger_info.aspx?from=Delhi&to=Manali&journey=21-Nov-2010

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to encrypt the address bar url using asp.net (VB) ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230969/how-to-encrypt-the-address-bar-url-using-asp-net-vb)

Comment: Could you please stop asking duplicate questions? If the original one sucked the new one sucks, too - edit your old one if you just want to add something. Besides that, look at some properly asked questions. You are at almost **-30** rep; that's quite an achievement.

Answer (score 0):

System.Security package is made to achieve it.For complete reference with code [Click here](http://devcity.net/printarticle.aspx?articleid=47)